# Animate one widget on clicking button in another widget in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[image]

I have two widgets in my app. The first widget creates a TableRow of buttons. The second widget is the Go Button.

On clicking the go button, I want to highlight (i.e. add color & then revert to normal) each of the buttons serially from 1 to 8. I am confused on how to animate the first widget on tapping the Go button which is defined in the second widget

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String apptitle = 'Test';

  Widget _goButtonClickCallback() {
    print("hello world. go tapped");
    // How do I control animation inside numListBuilder() from here? 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var numList = [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: apptitle,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(apptitle),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              NumberListBuilder(numList),
              SizedBox(height: 110),
              GoButton(_goButtonClickCallback)
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

NumberListBuilder.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NumberListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> numberList;
  const NumberListBuilder(this.numberList);

  @override
  _NumberListBuilderState createState() => _NumberListBuilderState();
}

class _NumberListBuilderState extends State<NumberListBuilder> {
  List<TableRow> getButtonRows() {
    // list for all rows
    List<TableRow> rows = [];
    int numCols = 2;
    int numberListLength = widget.numberList.length;
    int numRows = 4

    var k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      List<Widget> rowChildren = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        rowChildren.add(Container(
            height: 80.0,
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.white70,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                widget.numberList[k++],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            )));
      }
      rows.add(new TableRow(children: rowChildren));
    }
    return rows;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Table(
        border: TableBorder.all(),
        children: getButtonRows(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a state management library like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) this way you would have a provider class that listens to changes and when one the button is tapped you can notify all listeners to perform a certain action.

It's also better to maintain in the future than trying to pass different arguments throughout the widget tree